# How to execute Python3 scripts during runtime in Java?

Tags: python, java, python-3.x, jython

I want to run Python3 scripts during runtime in my Java application without having Python 3 installed on the system where I run the Java app (e.g. I ship single .jar to the customer).

I tried to use Jython, but it supports Python2 only.

How can I bundle the Python3 executable into the Java application and how can I then access it from my Python script?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Java is platform-agnostic. You'd have to include the Python executable for every single platform you want to target.

Comment: ok I see, do you know how I can specify in Java what path to the python executable it should use when executing the Python scripts?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try to make your python scripts to .exe, and simply run them using this code:

```
String command = "./script.exe";
 
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
 
// deal with OutputStream to send inputs
process.getOutputStream();
 
// deal with InputStream to get ordinary outputs
process.getInputStream();
 
// deal with ErrorStream to get error outputs
process.getErrorStream();
```

Not the most efficient way to do so, but it should probably do the job.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Does it work with command line arguments as well? E.g. "script.exe -a value -b value"?

Comment: I did not really try it since I rarely use command line arguments, but I think it does not work.